# How to access the environment variables in production in React App

Tags: reactjs, docker, build, environment-variables, production

Currently I was working on a project in which I required environment variables that were available in production.

While running the code locally I was able to access the environment variables using the `process.env.REACT_APP_VARIABLE` but I was not able to access it in production.

Can someone please suggest any solution, specifically for React application.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, environment variables should be accessible in production the same way they are in development. Do you have a way to check for this variable in the production server terminal?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.